# taylor approximation with respect to different variables on two sides of an equation.

Tags: taylor-expansion

If I have an equation that defines a relation between $x,y$:

$$f(x)=g(y)$$

> Is it valid to Taylor approximate these two sides of the equation
>   w.r.t. to different variables (lhs w.r.t $x$, rhs w.r.t. $y$)?
>
> i.e. $$f(0)+f'(0)x\approx g(0)+g'(0)y$$

Alternatively, is it valid to only approximate one side?

> $$f(x)\approx g(0)+g'(0)y$$

Or do we have to do both sides by the same variable?

> $$f(0)+f'(0)x\approx g(y)|_{x=0}+\left(\frac d {dx} g(y)|_{x=0}\right)\cdot x$$